# can't break line in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I wanted to output manual page in a text file.

```
root@uddhav-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~# man tcpdump >>a.txt /* I can output here */
root@uddhav-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~# man tshark >>a.txt /* I can't output here */
```

**Errors:**

```
<standard input>:1068: warning [p 14, 3.5i]: can't break line
<standard input>:1088: warning [p 14, 8.0i]: can't break line
```

I can read the manual page online. But sometimes, I don't have access to the internet, and I must be able to read the manual page in order to solve the things. I know I can read manual page using `man tshark`, but I wanted to output manual page in text file and later read via GUI editor.

I believe this error is coming because there is a bug in tshark binary file. But I am just curious if any of you guys solved it already?

Note: I also tried from a normal user. The same thing happens. tshark is command line version of Wireshark. You have to install tshark first using `sudo apt-get install tshark`

Comment: You know that you can do `man tshark` offline? You don't need internet for the man pages.

Comment: I know but manual page is too long, I want to output that in text file and read using GUI editor.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer you question, but you can generally pipe to a GUI editor: `man test | gedit -` for instance will pop open gedit on your Desktop and load it with the piped man file. That dash tells gedit (or whatever editor) to treat stdin as the file which it expects at that parameter position. So if you can launch your preferred GUI editor from the command line, then you can pipe to it as well.

Comment: @JNevill doing pipe and redirecting to output file is exactly same thing. My question is there is no error while doing redirection for tcpdump but there is while doing tshark.

Comment: Try `man tshark | col -b >> a.txt`

Comment: @Deathgrip, this doesn't solve the issue. In fact, it can't. In A | B, A output should be OK, and then only we do pipe (|) to filter out our A information. My problem is there is already error in A. It is now something like error | col -b >> a.txt

Comment: But you said earlier `man tshark` displays the man page. It doesn't?

Comment: @Deathgrip, it displays. But, in the terminal, I don't like to read. I want to read it in GUI editor (gedit). It is not the terminal command related problem. It is problem in tshark while redirecting to some output file.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the `MANWIDTH` variable. You can read more about it on the `man` manpage. Try pumping that variable up to something high before redirecting/piping: `MANWIDTH=100 man tshark > yourfile` [info found here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318538)

Comment: @JNevill, your idea solved the issue. But I put MANWIDTH=1000 instead of 100. You can explain this concept below. I will accept as answer. Thanks, man.

Comment: Glad to hear that did the trick!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This below comment from **@JNevill** solved the problem.

*Looks like it has something to do with the MANWIDTH variable. You can read more about it on the man manpage. Try pumping that variable up to something high before redirecting/piping: MANWIDTH=100 man tshark > yourfile*

After I adjusted the terminal width with `MANWIDTH=1000 man tshark > a.txt`, I found no errors.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this problem, I wanted a 70-column-wide man page for inclusion into a narrow document.

`stderr` could be piped to a subshell, which then filters out the error message using `grep`. Other errors would still be reported as usual. Here is an example of how to do that:

```bash
MANWIDTH=70 man podman 2> >(grep -v 'troff:.*break line')
```

You have several options on how to use the above one-liner. There are many factors to consider when choosing the appropriate option - so many that you might want to try them all to see what works best for you.

### Option 1: Define Bash Function

You could define the function in `.bashrc`:

```bash
function man {
  MANWIDTH=70 /usr/bin/man "$@" 2> >(grep -v 'troff:.*break line')
}

export -f man
```

#### Option 2: Define Bash Script

Save the following script in an executable file called `man`, somewhere in the path before `/usr/bin` ... for example, `/usr/local/bin/man`, or, for Ubuntu, `$HOME/.local/bin/man`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

MANWIDTH=70 /usr/bin/man "$@" 2> >(grep -v 'troff:.*break line')
```